# Should not reload while showing error message

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a login page which is working fine but the issue I'm facing is when I enter an invalid username, name or password.

It should show `"invalid username or password"` without loading the page, that is what AJAX is used right? But instead, when I enter an invalid username name or password, it is showing an error that the username name or password is invalid by loading the page which is not acceptable in case of AJAX.

Can anyone help me fix this issue that the error message should be shown without reloading of the page?

**login.php:**

```
<?php 

    session_start(); 
    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header('location:welcome.php');
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>

<head>
    <title> login script with ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#b3ffff">

    <div style="padding-left:500px ; padding-top:200px">

        Username:   <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br>
        Password:   <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Log In">
                    <p style="color:black">Havent Registered Yet? <a href="index.php">Register</a>.</p><br><br>
                    <div id="display" style="color:red"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                    var username = $("#username").val();
                    var password = $("#password").val();

                    var datastring = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

                    if(username=='' || password==''){
                        $("#display").html("Please Enter All The Fields");
                    }
                    else{
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "success.php",
                        data: datastring,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                                $("#display").html(result);
                                window.location = "welcome.php";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**success.php:**

```
<?php

    $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header('location:welcome.php');
    }

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $hashed_password=$row['password'];

    if(password_verify($mypassword, $hashed_password)) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['userid'];
        echo'Successfully Registered';
    exit();
    }    
    else 
    {
    echo'Invalid username or password';
    }
?>
```

**welcome.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div style="Padding-left:200px; padding-top:100px">
            <?php
                $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");
                $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
            ?>

            <br><br>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <br><br>

            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:56%">

                <div class="panel-heading text-center">STUDENT'S DETAILS</div>

            </div>  


        <div class="container text-center">

            <?php

                $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax1");

                if (!isset($_POST["happy"])) {  
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users");
                } else {
                            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["happy"]);
                            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users where department like '%$search%'");
                        } if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    echo "<table border='1' class='text-center' >
                    <tr>

                        <th>USER_ID</th>
                        <th>USERNAME</th>
                        <th>E-MAIL</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>AGE</th>
                        <th>DATE_OF_BIRTH</th>
                        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>

                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo 'Sorry no record found';
                            }

            ?>

        </div>


        <div class="container form-group">
            <br><br>
            <form method="post">
                <label class="control-label" style="color:blue">Select :</label>

                <select name="happy" style="margin-left:14px; color:black;">
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                                <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                                <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                                <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                                <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                                <option value="IS">Information Science</option> 
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>             
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off-topic but you should take a look at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: you are loading error message and right after changing page

Comment: if i enter any invalid username or password it should show error message invalid username or password without loading of the page but instead it is showing by loading the page

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get JSON Response like following:

```
{success: true} or {success: false}
```

and check it ajax success

```
if(result.success == true) {
 window.location = 'welcome.php';
}
```

OR in your code

```
if(result.indexOf('Successfully') > -1) {
 window.location = 'welcome.php';
}
```

Edit: Repo

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "success.php",
 data: datastring,
 cache: false,
 success: function(result){
  $("#display").html(result);
  if(result.indexOf('Successfully') > -1) {
   window.location = "welcome.php";
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: sir i tried what u said but its not working please can u edit my code and let me know please

Comment: Check my answer again, Use like that